# How can I recover photos from a damaged MacBook?

Tags: hard-drive, photos.app, recovery

My grandson spilled orange juice on my MacBook and ruined it. I bought an iPad to replace it, but I had dozens of old family pictures stored in iPhoto on the MacBook. Is there any way I can recover them and store them on my iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to an Apple store (or ask a friend with tech skills) to remove the hard drive from the MacBook.  Most likely the hard drive will be unharmed and putting it into an external USB case will let you access it (not necesarily directly via the iPad but through some other way, e.g. iCloud or USB stick or something).

Btw, quite likely the MacBook is not beyond repair also.  Ask an Apple tech.